# Better Recognition of Text using iOS 14 VNRecognizeTextRequest in Swift on Simulator then iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, ocr

I have built an App that using VNRecognizeTextRequest to recognize text from a picture. I have taken a poor picture on purpose (bad light, hand writing, not straight, etc) with my iPhone 8 Plus. Running my algorithm on the Simulator with various different device types renders excellent results (MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports), Catalina 10.15.6). I get some results on my iPhone 8 Plus but much poorer. Is this behavior to be expected?
Both are on iOS 14. Small code snippet below, using default .accurate and TopCandidates.

```
let request = VNRecognizeTextRequest(completionHandler: recognizeTextHandler)
func recognizeTextHandler(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
            guard let observations =
                    request.results as? [VNRecognizedTextObservation] else {
                return
            }
            let recognizedStrings = observations.compactMap { observation in
                // Return the string of the top VNRecognizedText instance.
                return observation.topCandidates(1).first?.string
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Google MLKit [Text recognition](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/ios) for better recognition for text from picture. It will process your image and return the text from picture with your requirements.

It's working and best for text recognition for me.

Thanks.